# Ubuntu no sound even when restarting/reinstalling pulseaudio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

the sound of my PC was suddenly bad (no bass, poor quality overall). I stopped and restarted pulseaudo, and since the was no improvement I ran `sudo apt install pulseaudio alsa-base alsa-utils` and `sudo alsa force-reload`. Now there is no sound at all, not even in the test sound. I have

```
$ inxi -SMA
System:
  Host: juggernaut Kernel: 5.11.0-49-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: GNOME 3.38.4 Distro: Ubuntu 21.04 (Hirsute Hippo) 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: MSI product: MS-7693 v: 4.0 
  serial: <superuser required> 
  Mobo: MSI model: 970 GAMING (MS-7693) v: 4.0 serial: <superuser required> 
  BIOS: American Megatrends v: 22.4 date: 12/21/2015 
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD SBx00 Azalia driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Device-2: NVIDIA GK208 HDMI/DP Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.11.0-49-generic
```

How can I get the sound back?

Thanks